# Unable to append image to div element, throws exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to make an image appear within a div that already contains a different image.

```
var enemies = $(".enemy");

var animateAll = function (hits) {
    for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
        if (hits[i + 1] != "") {
            enemies[i].append(animation(hits[i + 1])).fadeOut(150);
        };
    };
};

var animation = function (animationName) {
    return $('<img class=\"animation\" src=\"/Images/Animations/" + animationName + "Animation.png\" />');
};
```

But I am receiving the exception "Uncaught TypeError: Object #HTMLDivElement has no method 'append'"

Has the append() method been deprecated?

Comment: what is $(".enemy"); referring to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[When you index into a jQuery object, you get a DOM element](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/), not [a jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery). Change `enemies[i]` to `$(enemies[i])` or [`enemies.eq(i)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Answer (score 1):

You messed up while trying to concat the strings in your `animation()` function

```
return $('<img class=\"animation\" src=\"/Images/Animations/"' + animationName + '"Animation.png\" />');
```

Comment: I think I wrote that one out instead of copy/pasting (not sure why) but what you have here is what is actually on my page and it is still giving me the same error.